# Use PHP to add class to elements

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently creating a theme for Wordpress but I've hit an roadblock so close to completion!

I'm using a custom comments field and it's wrapped in a container with styling to it. However this container is built like this:

**Called to Main Template**

```
<?php comments_template();?>
```

**Inside comments.php which exists in my theme's directory**

```
<div class="tweleve columns row mytheme-box mytheme-body mytheme-form">
 <?php if (have_comments() ): ?>
  <h4 id="comments"><?php comments_number('No Comments','One Comment','% Comments');?></h4>
   <ol class="comment-list">
  <?php wp_list_comments('callback=custom_comments');?>
   </ol>
<?php endif;?>


<?php
 $comments_args = array(
  'label_submit'=>'Submit Comment',
  'title_reply'=>'Leave us a comment!',
  'comment_notes_after' => '',);
  comment_form($comments_args); ?>
  </div>
```

*mytheme-box turns the div into a box with a small shadow, border-radius etc.*

*mytheme-body styles the text within*

*mytheme-form is unique styling to the form.*

*twelve columns row is the styling from the skeleton framework*

**Inside the functions.php file**

```
function custom_comments ($comment, $args, $depth) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
        <header class="comment-header">
            <?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='48',$default='<path_to_url>'); ?>
            <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>

                <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID)) ?>"><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time())?></a><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Modify)'),' ','')?></div>
        </header>
            <br>
            <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
            <em><?php _e('Your comment is pending approval.') ?></em>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php comment_text()?>

<div class="reply">
    <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth'=>$depth, 'max_depth'=> $args['max_depth']))) ?>
    </div>
   </div>
   <hr>
  <?php
}
```

This is all fine, I have no problem with any thing here. The only issue I have is I've had to create a div to wrap everything comments related in which is what wraps around the code in comments.php. I do this because I don't want to touch the /wp-includes files even though it includes comments_template.php which is where I'd like to stick mytheme-body, box and form styles as it's where it get's made.

The reason being is because when I go into wordpress and turn off comments for a page, I'm left with an empty box where the comments use to be, and this is highly annoying. Is there anything I could do to fix this?

A way to maybe assign additional classes just to one already created element? Can I totally make my own comments_template.php and not rely on the core one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use another condition that checks if comments are enabled.
It can be easily achieved with the conditional tag [`comments_open`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_open).

In your `comments.php` file, above the opening `div` add:

```
if(comments_open()):

   //All of your code here
   ...
   ...
   ...

endif; //Use `else` if you want to show a notification.
```

Comment: You sir! - Thank you! I clearly tried to made this overly complicated and you just made it so much better for me :)